# Application Working Directory (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, directory, windows-installer

I am linking few excel and word files with my application. There is a predefined folder structure that holds all these files. i.e.

`Base\Engineering\A.xlsx`

`Base\Sales\B.xlsx`

and so on.

Now I want to link the "Base" folder with my application.

My current stupid solution is, to ask user to browse to the "Base" folder every time the application loads.

- What is the most efficient way to do this?
- In the end I want to create an installer for my application. I
   wish to use Windows "Program Files" folder to host my folder
   structure. This way users do not have to search for the "Base"
   folder.  How do I do this?

I am new to VB.NET.

Comment: @demongolem: Thank you so much for streamlining the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the All Users Application Data folder:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
```

There is also a per-User Application Data folder that you can reference. Which you need depends on what you're doing.